# Parse getCurrentUser info are not updated

Tags: java, android, parse-platform

**Hey**
Sorry if it is a stupid question, but this is really pissing me off.

```
if (ParseUser.getCurrentUser().getList("isFollowing") == null) {

        List<String> emptyList = new ArrayList<String>();
        ParseUser.getCurrentUser().put("isFollowing", emptyList);
    }
```

The problem in the code above is that it returns null the first time I run the app only, even when I make it null again.

This problem is every where in my code, the `getCurrentUser` method never returns the most recent information...

I think the problem is that the `getCurrentUser` method returns a cached version of the data. How do I update it?

I'm using `parse 1.13.0`, and `bolts tasks 1.3.0`.

Edit: 
Now I know that everything is screwed up when I use `ParseUser.getCurrentUser().saveInBackground();`

Does that help?

Edit 2:
The problem seems to be in the `saveInBackground()` method in the following code:

```
ParseUser.getCurrentUser().getList("isFollowing").add(users.get(
ParseUser.getCurrentUser().saveInBackground();
```

It runs great the first time I go through the save, but the second time and the rest does nothing...

I know I'm being annoying now, but I have been stuck with this problem for like 5 days...

Please help!

Comment: Does the ParseUser.getCurrentUser() return null or the getList()?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is how you refresh the current user:

```
ParseUser.getCurrentUser().fetchInBackground(new GetCallback<ParseObject>() {
        @Override
        public void done(ParseObject object, ParseException e) {

        }
    });
```

Comment: So, when I call the fetchInBackground() method, should I call the ParseUser.getCurrentUser() normally, or is the ParseObject object the currentUser?

Comment: just cast the object to ParseUser :  `(ParseUser) object`